# How to instantiate multiple objects of a class in run time?

Tags: java, input

I'm reading an input file which has data specific to a person in one line as comma separated values. i have successfully tokenized each line. Now,  I want to create different objects (with different variable names of course!) of type Person during run time as I read each line. Is this possible?

Comment: `"Now, I want to create different objects (with different variable names of course!) of type Person during run time as I read each line. Is this possible?"` -- Yes, it's possible. The details of the solution will of course depend on the details of your problem and code.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: Post the code of your `Person` class (including its constructor).

Comment: The file's contents aren't relevant to your question--you're asking if you can create multiple instance of `Person` and the answer is yes. I question creating "variables with different names" for each one, though, and would steer you to a collection instead.

Comment: Let's say the file has the following data:

John, 30, $5000
Jill, 25, $3000

Now there is a Person class with the Name, Age and Salary as private member variables. How can I instantiate Person in run time with different object names? The file might have any number of lines.

Comment: Objects **don't have names**. Do what @DaveNewton suggests -- create an `ArrayList<Person>` and fill it with Person objects.

Comment: @Dave Newton Use collections? Could you please explain with a simple example? I'm totally new to Java.

Comment: @user3837378 I would strongly recommend you to **study Java** and its main APIs and frameworks (Collections for first) or you won't be able to understand the answers you will be given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Now by doing this you created a list of objects of type `Person`.

Using the member data of `Person` you could save data from the file read to the `Persons`.

Like:

```
Person a = new Person();
a.setName(name);
myList.add(a);
```

Or you can do this by using the `constructer` of `Person` if it excepts `name`:

```
Person a = new Person(name);
myList.add(a);
```

Where `name` is concluded from the file just read.